# Combining two PDF pages into a single page?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

The overall attempt here is to have two PDF pages, with one of them being a "smaller" one going in the bottom right of the other PDF document. I've looked online but none of the solutions I've found so far work for me.

Here are a couple of solutions I've attempted:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\pdfFolder\mainPDF.pdf");

    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\temp\pdfFolder\secondaryPDF.pdf", FileMode.Append));

    doc.Open();
    PdfImportedPage page;

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    for(int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    { 
      page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
      table.AddCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
      doc.Add(table);
    }
```

and

```
    MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(finalStream);

    PdfManager pdfMan = new PdfManager();
    Persits.PDF.PdfDocument docOne = pdfMan.OpenDocument(@"C:\temp\pdfFolder\mainPDF.pdf");
    Persits.PDF.PdfDocument docTwo = pdfMan.OpenDocument(@"C:\temp\pdfFolder\secondaryPDF.pdf");

    MemoryStream docOneMem = new MemoryStream(docOne.SaveToMemory());
    MemoryStream docTwoMem = new MemoryStream(docTwo.SaveToMemory());

    docOneMem.Position = 0;
    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(docOneMem));
    docOneMem.Dispose();

    docTwoMem.Position = 0;
    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(docTwoMem));
    docTwoMem.Dispose();
    copy.Close();

    Persits.PDF.PdfDocument finalDoc = pdfMan.CreateDocument();
    Persits.PDF.PdfPage finalDocPage = finalDoc.Pages.Add();

    finalDocPage.Equals(finalStream);

    finalDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\pdfFolder\finalpdf.pdf");
```

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: *"Here are a couple of solutions I've attempted:"* - in which way don't they do what you expect?

Comment: @mkl Well, according to the authors they're working solutions, but the first one leads in a corrupt file and the second one leaves a plank file.

Comment: The first one at least requires a final `doc.Close()`. The second one is a hodgepodge.

Comment: @mkl the doc.Close(); throws an error that the file is empty.

Comment: Well, pull the `doc.Add(table)` after the loop, it makes no sense inside it.